# Why do I suddenly receive print notifications on Windows 10?

Tags: exploit, windows-10, rootkits, trojan, printers

I have seen whats's in the image.

But i don't have any printer.

OS: Windows 10 22H2

[image]

Comment: Absolutely nothing here suggests an information **security** problem, root-kit, trojan, exploit or similar, i.e. off-topic. Just because something is strange does not mean that there is an attack. More likely it is another issue, like a bug. See also [Windows update bug labels all printers as “HP LaserJet”](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2162806/windows-update-bug-labels-all-printers-as-hp-laserjet.html) which seems to describe what you experience, including the specific Laserjet model number.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.